# NextAuth Credential Provider with Prisma Adapter in Next12 does nothing

Tags: database, next.js, adapter, prisma, next-auth

I've setup my **Nextjs (Next12)** with **NextAuth CredentialsProvider** and use **Prisma Adapter** to persist user's session in the database.

I followed this [documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/prisma) here from NextAuth team themselves. But **nothing happen** after I clicked on login button.

#### To Note

Before that:-

- I've make sure to try get the data first from the database & it works just fine.
- I did also did try to just use the normal `session: { jwt: true, maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 }` instead of straight away use **Adapter**. Also works fine.

#### Question

Now, I just want to know whether it's possible or not to use `CredentialsProvider` with `Adapter` at all?

#### NextAuth API

Below are 2 examples or working one and not working one: `/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js`

- **working**: does not use `adapter`

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';

export default async function auth(req, res) {
  return await NextAuth(req, res, {
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    session: {
      jwt: true,
      maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 days
    }
    providers: [
      CredentialsProvider({
        async authorize(credentials) {
          const user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
            where: {
                email: credentials.email,
                password: credentials.password
            }
          });

          if (user !== null)
          {
              return user;
          }
          else {
            throw new Error('User does not exists. Please make sure you insert the correct email & password.')
          }
        }
      })
    ],
    callbacks: {
      redirect: async ({ url, baseUrl }) => {
        return baseUrl
      },
      jwt: async ({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) => {
        if (typeof user !== typeof undefined) token.user = user;
  
        return token
      },
      session: async ({ session, user, token }) => {
        token?.user && (session.user = token.user)
  
        return session
      }
    }
  })
}
```

- **not working**: using `prisma adapter`

```js
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

export default async function auth(req, res) {
  return await NextAuth(req, res, {
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    providers: [
      CredentialsProvider({
        async authorize(credentials) {
          const user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
            where: {
                email: credentials.email,
                password: credentials.password
            }
          });

          if (user !== null)
          {
              return user;
          }
          else {
            throw new Error('User does not exists. Please make sure you insert the correct email & password.')
          }
        }
      })
    ],
    callbacks: {
      redirect: async ({ url, baseUrl }) => {
        return baseUrl
      },
      jwt: async ({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) => {
        if (typeof user !== typeof undefined) token.user = user;
  
        return token
      },
      session: async ({ session, user, token }) => {
        token?.user && (session.user = token.user)
  
        return session
      }
    }
  })
}
```

#### Prisma Schema

This is the current `schema.prisma` (this comes from the NextAuth doc itself):-

- I already did the `npx prisma migrate dev` & `npx prisma generate`

```js
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["referentialIntegrity"]
}

datasource db {
  provider             = "mysql"
  url                  = env("DATABASE_URL")
  // shadowDatabaseUrl    = env("SHADOW_URL")
  referentialIntegrity = "prisma"
}

model Account {
  id                 String  @id @default(cuid())
  userId             String
  type               String
  provider           String
  providerAccountId  String
  refresh_token      String?
  access_token       String?
  expires_at         Int?
  token_type         String?
  scope              String?
  id_token           String?
  session_state      String?
  oauth_token_secret String?
  oauth_token        String?

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
}

model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(cuid())
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       String
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  password      String?
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
}

model VerificationToken {
  identifier String
  token      String   @unique
  expires    DateTime

  @@unique([identifier, token])
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just found out the `CredentialsProvider` from `next-auth` will not work with `adapter` at all according to this [doc](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/credentials). You may find the reason why it can't or not recommended to use with `CredentialsProvider`.

This is an additional [link](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/2248) where you can find a discussion regarding this matter.

Comment: So, how to persist session in db, using prisma let's say?

Comment: @killjoy Based on the docs. Only when using `CredentialsProvider` you can't persist session in db. Basically you can use any adapter. Doesn't have to be prisma.

Comment: this design is correct and makes total sense because if you are using Credentials, you can just save directly to DB, why use an adapter? The reason for adapters is that they allow you to get access to the user data not coming from your web app.